# How do I convert a csv file to an inline dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I convert a CSV table like this:

```
|url                   |skin   |paws|
|https://demo.foo/cats |Fur    |YES |
|https://demo.foo/dogs |Fur    |YES |
|https://demo.foo/fish |Scales |NO  |
```

into an inline DataFrame, like this?

```
df = {'url': 'https://demo.foo/cats', 'https://demo.foo/dogs', 'https://demo.foo/fish'],   
      'skin': ['Fur', 'Fur','Scales'],  
      'paws' ['YES','YES','NO']}
```

I have tried `pd.read_csv(foo).to_dict(orient='records')` and `to_list`, but none of them output the format above.

I've been searching for three hours for an answer.  I think this is such a dumb question, that I don't think anyone has ever asked it.

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='list')` ?

Comment: That was it. I poured over the documentation looking for something like that, but didn't find it.  How to I mark your comment as correct?

Comment: What do you mean by an "inline data frame"??? That is a `dict`, not a `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Use pandas fixed width reader -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721429/how-do-i-read-a-fix-width-format-text-file-in-pandas

Comment: you could find it in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) : `‘list’ : dict like {column -> [values]}` , nevertheless, it is actually a duplicate :)